# Magento Backup Error

Tags: magento, backup, web-hosting, magento-1.6

I moved my magento site from godaddy to hostgator. I copied all the files to hostgator, then imported the database from godaddy to hostgator. 
But, the new site has few problems, like few item pages are missing like - `http://119.18.58.85/~homehero/index.php/shop/seating/union-jack-arm-chair (hostgator site),` same link from godaddy site - http://homehero.in/index.php/shop/seating/union-jack-arm-chair.

Comment: i can see item in both the sites. what's the problem?

Comment: are you able to open both mentioned above links ? When I click on the item - 'Union Jack arm chair' ( http://119.18.58.85/~homehero/index.php/shop/seating/union-jack-arm-chair  ) from the shop page ( http://119.18.58.85/~homehero/index.php/shop/seating ), it does not open.

Comment: I'm able to open both the links. they are displaying same content.

Comment: I have checked the link on different machines/browsers, it does no work, moreover I cannot see it working via proxy - http://3.hidemyass.com/index.php?e=curl_error&return=http%3A%2F%2F3.hidemyass.com%2Fbrowse.php%3Fu%3DOi8vMTE5LjE4LjU4Ljg1L35ob21laGVyby9pbmRleC5waHAvc2hvcC9zZWF0aW5nL3VuaW9uLWphY2stYXJtLWNoYWly%26f%3Dnorefer%26idx%3D1&p=Empty%20reply%20from%20server

Comment: I can also see both pages links working, you should do just indexing once again and everything will be fixed if there is some problem.

Comment: I re indexed all the indexed, cleared cache several times, but still the link does not work. While re indexing, the link worked for a while then stopped working again. If I remove the category i.e 'seating' from the url, it always works, but with the category it won't

Answer (score 0):

First of all that 'index.php' in your URL is not pretty - enable URL rewrites in admin config to fix that.

What you might want to do to reset all your URLs and get them to what they should be is empty the core_url_rewrite table. You will need to reindex after that, however, they should all be clean and work properly with no mystery product id's tacked onto the end of any URLs.

You will need to clear down core_url_rewrite with phpmyadmin or command line mysql.

Hope that helps.